# Updating joomla site in production from developpement server

Tags: php, joomla

I've two sites buit on joomla. Theye are respectivly hosted in two defferent servers. The first one is the developpement machine and the other is where is the production.
I frequently modify articles, some files... in the developpement machine. I would like to know wether it is possible to update automatically the production each time i modify something !

I don't want to use FTP for that!

Answer (score 1):

Had a look on the Joomla forums for stuff on this. Found a related thread [here](http://forum.joomla.org/viewtopic.php?p=2010586).

Basically the solution described here was to use a program called [MiToDirChangesWatcher](http://mito-team.com) which monitored directories on one server for changes and mirrored the changes on another server.

This doesn't handle the DB side of things though, so they just used phpMyAdmin to drop the production machines tables and do a dump from the development server. You could write a script  (python, shell etc) to do this for your without much trouble though.

Comment: thank's a lot. Finally I find a very good component. It allows me to have a copy of my website ( files and data base).
So I can update the copy by updating the master site. The oter is called child.
The componet name is wc copy manager